# RecyclerView takes up all screenspace

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

So I'm having some trouble with a RecyclerView in a layout file

Here it is:

> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>     android:id="@+id/chat_listview"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:paddingRight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_padding_material"
>     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_padding_material"
>     />
>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_below="@id/chat_listview"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     >
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/chat_input_edittext"
>         android:layout_weight="7"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
>         />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/chat_send_button"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:background="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"
>         />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
> ```

The RecyclerView is visible and scrollable but the LinearLayout and the Views inside are not visible... I tried quite a few things but nothing has worked so far.

Can any of you please point me into the right direction?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: http://imgur.com/wUFzgPv here is a screenshot of what I see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the root view to a FrameLayout. Set the gravity of the LinearLayout to bottom

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chat_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_padding_material"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_padding_material"
/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/chat_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chat_input_edittext"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chat_send_button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the linear layout in a FrameLayout
and set it to align_parentBottom = true if it is a relative layout or a linear layout at your root and you have other things in your view.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also added a padding at the bottom of the RecyclerView so there would be no text behind the LinearLayout.

Comment: There is no android:layout_below attribute for FrameLayout. Adding a padding is a workaround that I really don't advise. RelativeLayout and LinearLayout should work.

Answer (score 9):

When RecyclerView is drawn, it calculates all the remaining size on screen to itself before drawing the next elements and don't recalculate after the other elements are drawn, leaving them outside the screen.

The trick is to draw all other elements first, and leave RecyclerView for last. FrameLayout does not work anymore so use a relative layout and put the RecyclerView last on the XML layout file.

Example to add a bar with buttons below the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pagination_btns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"> //HERE YOU ALIGN THIS ELEMENT TO THE BOTTOM OF THE PARENT
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/previous_btn_label"/>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/next_btn_label"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/items_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@id/pagination_btns"/> //HERE YOU ALIGN THE RECYCLERVIEW ABOVE THE PAGINATION BAR 


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Should be the selected answer! `FrameLayout` is terrible to deal with and you gave an explanation. Thank you!

Comment: After maybe 3 hours searching and testing everything, here it is: simple and well explained answer ! Thanks !

Comment: You are lucky. It took me a few days to figure it out. I'm glad it helped.