# RecyclerView wrap_content

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to center a RecyclerView when its **layout_width** is **wrap_content** without success

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_schemes"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When the RecyclerView is given any definite layout_width of say 200dp then it does center otherwise it just aligns left.

How to make the RecyclerView center_horizontal when its layout_width is wrap_content ?

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33849954/1464539

Comment: please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35623177/2826147)

Comment: try this `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`, hope this help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is related on how the LayoutManager calculates the sizes. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772) you have the related bug with some workarounds people have used.

**NOTE**: With the release 23.2 of the support library now the wrap content is supported, so looks like they fixed it. You can checkout the changelog [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Answer (score 11):

According to your question, update on **(march 2016)**

I suggest you to update to [Android Support Library 23.2.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) **to support WRAP_CONTENT in RecycleVie**w.

In RecyclerView **layout_width** to **wrap_content** was not supported before 23.2.1.

solved some issue like *Fixed bugs related to various measure-spec methods*

Check http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_.

Comment: okay. i have change content of my answer and will follow your advice.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try using a `RelativeLayout` instead of Linear Layout and then make the Recyclerview `layout_centerHorizontal="true"`