# Center alignment of RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am following this tutorial
http://www.exoguru.com/android/ui/recyclerview/custom-android-grids-using-recyclerview.html
and I've minimized the the total number of element to 4.
I want to view the recyclerView at middle of the screen.but When I use "wrap_content" as it's height, the recyclerView is showing at the top of the screen.But if I specifies the height of it (for example: "350dp") it is showing at the center of the screen as i wanted.What went wrong when is use "wrap_content"

[image]

Comment: If you are only showing 4 items at once, why are you using a `RecyclerView`? The chances of those items ever being recycled is near 0.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView's concept is supposed to displaying a lot of items, which overflows out of the screen. And recycling (re-using) a minimal set of Views to show a bunch of items.

About your case, there are too few items to fill up the screen. So this is not weird.

Answer (score 0):

"Wrap_content" does not work properly with RecyclerViews (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867709/recyclerview-wrap-content)), but there are some solutions to this problem on [this site](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772).

If all you want to do is center the RecyclerView vertically, you could do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"/>

  <Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```