# RecyclerView wrap_content not working.TextView after it not showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've stumped in a problem I can't solve. I've got a fragment with a `CardView` containing a `RecyclerView`. This `RecyclerView` has `layout_height="wrap_content"` but i can see this is not working. I've read some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867825/579895) here saying that in version 23.2 of the support library this is fixed, but it doesn't work in my case. Also, i want a `TextView` right below the `CardView`, but it is not showing it. It's working fine if i give the `CardView` a fixed height.

I hope someone could help with this.

**EDIT**
Let's see if this image explains better what i mean.

[image]

Here,the `RecyclerView` limits are the blue rectangle, while they should be similar to the red one, that is what i want to archieve.

### build.gradle

```
dependencies{
          compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.+'
}
```

### layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
          >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp">
          <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

          </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="test text"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Comment: So you want your layout to contain both recyclerview and a text view?

Comment: @Eenvincible well,that's the idea. But the main problem is the `ReciclerView` wrap_content not working. The textview problem could be solved with a layout with weigths i believe,but then it won't be right below.

Comment: Have wrap_content for the RecyclerView will definitely hide the text view below when you have enough items to fill up the visible layout; that is why setting a height will make the textview visible. Let me try an answer from what I have

Comment: Yes,you are right @eenvincible,but it also happens when there's only one element in the recyclerview,so the real problem is the recyclerview getting all the available space, so it's not wrapping the content...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, at last I made it work. I don't like to answer my own question, but maybe can help others.

I was blaming `RecyclerView`,but the guilty was `SwipeRefreshLayout`. And in fact I as a newbie was the guilty. The problem was that I was putting the `SwipeRefreshLayout` inside the `CardView`. For what I can see, `SwipeRefreshLayout` tries to get all the available space (I think it is a logical behaviour) so that's why my `CardView` was doing the same.

So the solution is simple: on top, put the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, inside it a `LinearLayout` and inside it the `CardView` with the `RecyclerView` and the `TextView`.

Hope this could help other newbies as me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an `<include @layout/some_layout />` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

 <!-- Wrap this whole thing in a cardView -->
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/recycler"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

  <!-- End of cardview layout -->

  <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
     android:text="test text"
     android:layout_below="@id/recycler"
     android:textSize="20sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I am starting to think also is to place both recyclerview and the textview inside your card view. That means making CardView be your Root Layout. Just my thoughts!

Comment: Ok,i'll try it and i'll come back with the results. Thank you

Comment: I've tried and same results. As i told before, the problem is the RecyclerView taking up all the available space

Comment: Okay then I would suggest putting both recyclerview and textview inside one CardView

Comment: Yes,that would solve the textview problem,but...it doesn't look right. Forget about the TextView, the cardview is extending to fill all available space, and what i want is it to just have the contents height, so it really wraps the items in the recyclerview. Thanks for your ideas anyway :)

Comment: You can see the image in my updated question to better understand what i mean