# RecyclerView in SwipeRefreshLayout not "wrap_content"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, android-wrap-content

I have a `RecyclerView` as the only child of `SwipeRefreshLayout`, I want the RecyclerView `wrap_content`. When I set both of them "wrap_content", it doesn't work. The `RecyclerView` with fewer items also `match_parent`. When i delete `SwipeRefreshLayout`, the `RecyclerView` will `wrap_content`. Can anyone help me? My English is poor, Maybe you cann't understand.  Anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_v"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ffff">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff00ff">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: post xml code plz.and try wrap_content for SwipeRefreshLayout too

Comment: I have already set the `SwipeRefreshLayout` to `wrap_content`, but the `RecyclerView` is also `match_parent`

Answer (score 16):

Finally, I work out it. From [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392908/6491988)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_v"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff00ff"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now I have problem where my ScrollView starts to refresh in middle not only when reaching top, as it should, because of LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use Layout wrap RecyclerView. Beacause of SwipeRefreshLayout use `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` mode measure mTarget size when onMeasure()：

```java
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mTarget == null) {
            ensureTarget();
        }
        if (mTarget == null) {
            return;
        }
        mTarget.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight(),
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                getMeasuredHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        ......
    }
```

And mTarget is the first child view of SwipeRefreshLayout. So this will cause the mTarget always match parent.

```java
    private void ensureTarget() {
        // Don't bother getting the parent height if the parent hasn't been laid
        // out yet.
        if (mTarget == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (!child.equals(mCircleView)) {
                    mTarget = child;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

FrameLayout is used because it is more lightweight.

```xml
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                tools:itemCount="2"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_msg_detail_text_style" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with AndroidX

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/rooms">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>



</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```