# SwipeRefreshLayout wrap_content not working with ListView in Dialogfragment

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout, dialogfragment, android-wrap-content

I'm trying to set `SwipeRefreshLayout` which contains children `ListView` to **wrap_content** in a `DialogFragment`.

to actually make the **Dialog** wrap the height of it's childrens, because it's always filling the **window height** even if the **ListView** has only **one item**.

**Layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/devider_line"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/myButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result :**

[image]

I need to make the **DialogFragment** window scale height depending on the **ListView** items, not always fill the window height.

by making either the `SwipeRefreshLayout` or the `ListView` to wrap the content (items).

I've tried alot of ways to do that but nothing worked.

How can i achieve this?

**Update :**

The `SwipeRefreshLayout` itself is filling the entire **window height** and ignoring `wrap_content`.

i replaced `ListView` with `RecyclerView` and the `RecyclerView` is wrapping content height, which is good. but still `SwipeRefreshLayout` is **filling height** forcing the **DialogFragment** to cover all the **Window**.

i'm setting the dialog height to `wrap_content` :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    super.onResume();
}
```

Here's **list_item.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="18dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:text="@string/default_text" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/default_text"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:background="@color/devider_color" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update 2 :**

Using `RecyclerView` and **Wrapping** it with `LinearLayout` so **wrap_content** works on it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff00ff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/myButton" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But still `SwipeRefreshLayout` is filling the height.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` is behaving like this, try to override this behavior with this subclass

```
public class WrapingHeightListView extends ListView {

    public WrapingHeightListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WrapingHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public WrapingHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }

}
```

use `<com.yourpackage.WrapingHeightListView...` in your XML instead of current `<ListView ...` tag

or you may switch to `RecyclerView`, it handles `wrap_content` height properly (but this will need also some small adapter refactoring)

Comment: The extended ListView class maybe working but i can't tell because the SwipeRefreshLayout still filling the entire window ignoring it's wrap_content. is that normal? i'll see RecyclerView but i wish i could stick with ListView.
Maybe the RecyclerView it'self also fill parent because the SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't apply wrap_content to itself!

Comment: Confirmed that the SwipeRefreshLayout is the thing that filling the entire window, removed it and the RecyclerView wrap_content works. how to deal with SwipeRefreshLayout to wrap_content with RecyclerView within it!

Comment: [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945022/recyclerview-in-swiperefreshlayout-not-wrap-content) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649095/how-to-make-swiperefreshlayout-wrap-content) on stack overflow suggests wrapping `ListView` or `RecyclerView` in `LinearLayout`. And they are confirming that your wrong behavior comes from `SwipeRefreshLayout`, so above subclassed `WrapingHeightListView` may not be needed (still worth trying)

Comment: None of them worked.. i always see the ```SwipeRefreshLayout``` is filling the height ignoring ```wrap_content``` that's the issue, the ```RecyclerView``` works with wrap_content.

Comment: can you post list item XML? some another answers are suggesting setting `wrap_content` also to dialogs `Window` like this `dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp)` (`lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams`)

Comment: I've added the ```list_item.xml``` to the above .. and i already set the dialog height to wrap content using ```getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);``` on ```@Override onResume()```

Comment: list item looks fine (all `ViewGroup`s have `wrap_content` for height). can you confirm that without `SwipeRefeshLayout` `ListView` is wraping content properly keeping footer visible? I'm asking because you are using `wrap_content` for `RelativeLayout`, in which you have view (footer) with `layout_alignParentBottom`. quote from the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html):

Comment: `Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.` Maybe not `SwipeRefreshLayout`, but this one param set for footer makes your dialog expand?

Comment: See last update above.. you're right ```alignParentBottom``` may cause the dialog to fill the window.. but now i removed everything and left the ```SwipeRefreshLayout``` with ```RecyclerView``` and it's still filling the height.

Comment: sadly now I don't have a clue, sorry... tough case :/

Comment: Nevermind, thanks anyway for the help! appreciate it.