# Custom GridlayoutManager for WRAP_CONTENT on a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` in a `NestedScrollview`. I want my `RecyclerView` wrap its content for this im using a custom Linear Layout Manager. Which wrap `RecyclerView` content and working fine.

I achieve using [this](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager) library

which I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview/29945693#29945693) post.

Now I want to use `GridLayoutManager` for grid view which will wrap its content. 
Can Anyone Help?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: *grid view which will wrap its content* , I did not understand this part.Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32526403) answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: i am using RecyclerView in NestedScrollview.. So RecyclerView dont show its item list.. so i want to calculate its height according to its total item. Then set its height to that value.

Comment: I believe my explanation here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33849954/1464539